# Is there any difference between the -logic, -logical, and -logous suffixes?

Tags: adjectives, suffixes, ic-ical

For example: *tautologic*, *tautological*, and *tautologous*.

Comment: What has a dictionary told you about the differences?

Comment: @MattЭллен I'm not asking about my example words in particular. They were just examples.

Comment: You can look up suffixes in dictionaries. E.g. [-logic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-logic?q=-logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For -ic vs -ical see a [Metrolingua](http://blog.metrolingua.com/2009/05/ic-vs-ical-distinctions-can-be-fickle.html) entry that basically states that most uses overlap almost entirely, but in some cases there is a distinction, as in economic vs economical, where economical implies thrifty, and economic really just refers to anything relating to economy. I don't know if this applies to any examples of the -ogous suffix.

The article further describes an adjective politic that meands prudent, and historic, which means a significant event in history, not just any event.

Comment: I think those differences relating to *economic, politic, historic* simply reflect the fact that people have exploited the original synonymy to create useful distinctions. I doubt very much that any correspondingly useful distinction could be made around the word *tautological*.

Comment: That is the nature of this horrible language, as far as I can tell. People constantly apply connotations to words that are essentially fully synonymous, and some horrible system of evolution takes place that produces such disparity with little explanation.

Comment: I certainly agree that's one of the ways language evolves, but I wouldn't say this process is *"horrible"*. In fact, I think it's both useful (our world changes, so we're always needing new words), and inherently fascinating (how lanuage usage changes over time can give real insights into our history/culture/etc.). Anyway, I think you have to admit ELU is hardly the best place to call English a *horrible language* (probably few people here are likely to agree with such a comment! :)

Comment: English being useful does not make it good at what it does. Evolution functioning for its purpose does not mean it does so well. People need to differentiate between crude functionality and truly effective functionality, between tolerable, good, and great. As for this being an appropriate place, if I can't criticize the language on its own turf in a Q&A site, then where can I?

Comment: Secondly, reusing old words is not the same as creating new ones. As for as fascination, etymology is as fascinating as the math used in nutrition labels.

Comment: Well I suppose in principle [Esperanto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto), being a "designed" language, should be far better than English by your lights. But Wikipedia says there are only 10K-2M people who speak it - and even if there were 10 times more than their upper "guestimate", I'd still say the language is an abject failure. Would you criticise sex, say, just because it can get a bit messy?

Comment: What alternatives are you giving for sex? You managed to find a possibly shittier language than English, and that makes Engilsh competitive? Your examples are fairly horrible.

Comment: @shinyspoongod I'm enjoying the debate with FumbleFingers. But really, what alternative would you give for English? It is what it is at this point in its history. I agree English must be incredibly frustrating to learn, but on the other hand it has a gorgeous richness.

Comment: All I'm saying in the end is that English is too full of exceptions to the rules to be tolerable for these poor bastards who have to learn it as a second language. It may or may not be interesting that the langage is chock-full of obscure loanwords and phonetic exceptions, homonyms, alternate spellings, and such, but these are all pitfalls for the writer/speaker. They aren't entirely unavoidable, but they don't need to be this common.

Comment: @JAM I don't propose any alternatives. That was never the point of any single comment or the conversation as a whole. I simply stated that it is a frustrating language in a tone of voice that prompted its defense by someone who took offense, likely because s/he is quite schooled in it after years of hard work.

Comment: I say all this with English being my first language.

Answer (score 0):

They're effectively synonyms, but [most people use **tautological** most of the time...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tautologic,tautological,tautologous&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]